# javascript function returns undefined instead of object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started working a bit with javascript but quickly got stuck with a - in my eyes - quite simple task of returning an object literal.

The code I currently have looks like this

```
function wrapInObject(x)
{
    return
    {
        y: x
    };
}
console.log(wrapInObject('someValue'));
```

but instead of writing the object literal to the console it prints `undefined` - I tried calling the function with numbers or other object literals but nothing helped.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: Yep, white space is killing you. remove the return after the return

Comment: Wow - thx a lot guys! No commercial expensive support etc. could be faster :D

Comment: That is the reason why you should always write your functions like `function f() {...` or object literal expressions like `return {...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a process known as [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Automatic_Semicolon_Insertion) and is quite often the source of confusion for new devs with a C# background or other languages where placing the opening brace on a new line is common practice.

Essentially what happens is that an implicit semicolon is placed right after your `return` statement so that it returns `undefined` and your object literal is never 'reached'.

To fix it just move the opening brace to the end of the `return` like so

```
function wrapInObject(x)
{
    return { 
        y: x 
    };
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I copy pasted the code and it worked because my text editor fixed the carriage return.

Answer (score 0):

Because of automatic semicolon insertion

```
function wrapInObject(x)
{
    return
    {
        y: x
    };
}
console.log(wrapInObject('someValue'));
```

gets converted to

```
function wrapInObject(x)
{
    return ; // semicolon is added
    {
        y: x
    };
}
console.log(wrapInObject('someValue'));
```

Hence you get undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of semicolon auto-insertion adding a line break after the return statement makes the js engine parse that line as if there was a semicolon. Move the opening bracket to the same line as the return statement.

[Another StackOverflow entry about semicolon auto-insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)